# Getting AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] Frequently

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-ios

Could any tell me what exactly is the reason to, why I am getting the following error ?

> AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:254 | __41-[AWSURLSessionManager taskWithDelegate:]_block_invoke208 | Invalid AWSURLSessionTaskType.

Comment: I have been having this error for quite long and cannot find an answer. It only happens when I download many files in a short period of time (scrolling very fast), event cancelling the request. The problem for me is that the Task block doesn't return, so I cannot handle it to notify the users that something bad happened. Please let me know if you find something

Comment: I'm getting the this error, can you help me out please.AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCredentialsProvider.m line:428 | __73-[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider getCredentialsWithCognito:authenticated:]_block_invoke | GetCredentialsForIdentity failed.

Comment: Could you provide more details to this ? What causes the error? Is the solution posted below related and solves the issue for you? Thanks

Comment: Hope this will solve your question ? https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a little bit late but I just found a solution that worked for me.

Now, it might be different because it really depends on your code.
For example, I was having the problem by trying to send a PutItem request to DynamoDB, and my problem was that I didn't initialize the PutItemInput object.

```
AWSDynamoDBPutItemInput *request = [AWSDynamoDBPutItemInput alloc];
```

Should be:

```
AWSDynamoDBPutItemInput *request = [[AWSDynamoDBPutItemInput alloc] init];
```

After initializing it the code worked perfectly.